# Amazon EC2 replace old pem file with a new pem file

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssh, amazon-ec2

After taking over a server on EC2 I was given a PEM file to access the instance. For security reasons I would like to generate a new PEM file now, but it looks like you can't create new Key Pairs without creating a new instance. Is there anyways to create a new PEM file?

Comment: What type of server? Linux or windows? Generating a new PEM file is easy.  You want to use the new key to access the server? Can you access it now with the given PEM?

Comment: Its a linux server, I can access it now with the PEM but want to generate a new one that can also access the server

Comment: Treat the running instance as a remote server.  Log in to the instance with the private key of the old PEM and install the public key of the new PEM for each user you want to be able to log in directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming Linux, use `ssh-keygen` to create a new key pair. Let us say `new.pem` and `new.pub`

Now ssh into the instance with your `old.pem`. Open 2 or 3 sessions with the `old.pem` just in case the new pem fails. Assuming your username is `ubuntu`

1. cd /home/ubuntu/.ssh
2. Make a copy of the existing `authorized_keys` file
3. Now open  `authorized_keys` and replace its contents with `new.pub`
4. Save  `authorized_keys`
5. Now ssh into the instance with `new.pem`

If ssh is successful, then you can use the `new.pem` from now on and the `old.pem` is no longer valid. If ssh is not successful, restore the old `authorized_keys` file in one of the backup sessions and start again from step 1.

Answer (score 0):

Login in to system using the existing key.

```
$ cd /home/ubuntu/.ssh/
```

Now there is only one file(authorized_keys) in this folder.

Genereate a new set of keys using the command below

```
$ ssh-keygen
```

### Once the command is executed, there are two files created as below

?pemnew            > This file is the new .pem file to be used by us to ssh

?pemnew.pub    > This file has contents which need to be added to authorized_keys in the server.

---

Copy the content of ?pemnew.pub and add it in authorized_keys and remove the existing entry in authorized_keys.

Testing:

Open new terminal-tab and try to ssh using the new key

- generated(?pemnew).  Expected behaviour : Connection allowed

Open another terminal-tab and try to ssh using the old key.

- Expected behaviour (entry in authorized_keys is removed): Refused
- Expected behaviour (entry in authorized_keys is not removed): Allowed